# How to do grouping in Rollbar using monolog handler?

Tags: php, yii, error-logging, monolog, rollbar

I am using Monolog handler in Yii framework to capture errors in Rollbar. Now I need to introduce grouping feature in Rollbar to my code. Since I am using Monolog, I cannot do it by passing the parameter. Instead I need to search some other way. Interested in getting some help from you all guys.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Surya - Have you spoken to Rollbar support yet?  I don't know the answer off the top of my head but one of my colleagues should be able to help you out.

Comment: Hi Jesse Gibbs - I have tried Rollbar support. It seems like Monolog handler is not Rollbar maintained and I don't find any steps to pass fingerprint variable with monolog handler.

Comment: Have you tried using the [monolog support in rollbar-php](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-php/#using-monolog) - This is our officially-supported notifier and should support sending your own fingerprint.

Comment: Not yet Jesse Gibbs, I will try it and let you know.